# update hiddenfield using jquery on pageloadcomplete VB.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

okay i have been trying to understand this for hours i am learning VB :

if i have this ( PageLoadComplete function / HiddenField / linkButton )  :

```
 Protected Sub PageLoadComplete(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles     Me.LoadComplete
    If Request.QueryString("viewPDF") = 1 Then
        MsgBox(myfield.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

this link open a new tab linked to the same page (it loads the same page ) :

```
   <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="lnkBtn" ID="btnViewPDF" 
 OnClientClick="var url = 'CIP_frmCIPEventExplore.aspx?ViewPDF=1;
  parent.showNewTab(url, 'CIP Chart - PDF', 'CIP');">
  <img alt=""src="External_Files/images/view_pdf_icon.png" />
   <span>View MsgBox</span></asp:LinkButton>
```

and hidden field  that has a value  :

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="myfield" runat="server" Value="myfields" />
```

IF i click on the link it open a new tab with a MsgBox that has the HiddenField (ID="myfield") value which is very fine but :

if i modify this hidden field and remove it's value like this :

```
   <asp:HiddenField ID="myfield2" runat="server" />
```

and then add this value using javascript:

```
   $("#<%=btnViewPDF.ClientID%>").click(function(){
               $("#<%=myfield2.ClientID%>").val('this is the field2 val') ; ) ; 
            });
```

i get an empty MsgBox() , so how can i make the jquery update this hidden field ID="myfield2" before calling the PageLoadComplete function 
Thanks

Comment: should your `.val` statement be `$("#<%=myfield2.ClientID%>")`?

Comment: yes even with this didn't work

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood what you're trying to do.  PageLoadComplete gets executed long before the page gets rendered to the browser.  if you want to update the value of the hidden field, do `myfield.Value = "somevalue"`

Comment: what i am trying to do is to update the myfield2 so it can be seen oncode behind  when click the linkButton using javascript ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have two click events defined for `btnViewPDF`, so they are likely conflicting with each other. Try moving the Javascript from the `OnClientClick` property into the jQuery `click()` function.